# JSON framework when saving to MySql database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Ok I'm still learning the JSON framework and objective c.. But my question is I have a php/MySQL  server from godaddy and basically what I'm trying to do is create a user registration which sends that data FROM MY IOS registration form into MySQL database to my Registration table.. What is the best way to post the information when the user is done entering their username, password and so on.. I'm a lil stuck on the best method to go about this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is your best friend.